# cfthread with heavy DB activity

Tags: coldfusion

When we enter a ticket in system, there is an insert in a group of 5-6 tables (based on some rules). That works alright when single ticket is added manually.
Now we have a requirement where we will get the ticket feed from external source (most probably a xml or may be a txt file). It can have any number of tickets up to 500.

If I have to leverage the cfthread, and say 10 threads of 50 tickets each, how I can prevent it to cause issue on DB. Ultimately, everyone of those tickets will be inserting data in same Db tables.
As each thread will be completely independent, would't it create queue on DB (may be a deadlock too)?
Environment: CF2016, SQL Server2014

Comment: I suggest a main thread to receive the data and thank the user, and one other thread to loop through and process the data.

Comment: If the different threads are inserting rows, then there shouldn't be any conflicts.  If the separate threads update different rows, then again, there should be no conflicts.  However, if the separate threads update any rows that are the same, then you'd want to implement record level locking during these updates for any potential concurrency issues.

Comment: This is really a DB question, not a CFML or application-threading question. I recommend you re-word / -tag it appropriately. That said, unless you're using MS Access on a 286, the load you are describing is inconsequential so any load issues that arise would point to bad application design more than anything else. Given we can't see your application, I'm not sure this is really an answerable question as it stands. I recommend you identity a specific problem and ask specific, well-worded question.